# Why DateTime is converted to TimeStamp after updating data in Firestore Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, google-cloud-firestore, datetimepicker

I'm trying to update `SfCalendar` event in `Firestore`.

For that I can change the title, add a comment, and modify beginning and ending dates.

But I've noticed 2 problems.

**First problem**

If I change the title, the beginning and ending date nothing is updated in Firestore

The logcat shows this:

[image]

Firestore shows this before & after update:

[image]

**Second problem**

If I upadte the title&/the comment and don't change the dates. The dates are automatically Converted from `DateTime` to `TimeStamp`

Before update:

[image]

Logcat:

[image]

After update without changing dates:

[image]

Here is the code

**Utils**

```
static String toDateTime(DateTime dateTime, BuildContext context) {
    var locale = Localizations.maybeLocaleOf(context)?.toLanguageTag();
    final date = DateFormat.yMMMEd(locale).format(dateTime);
    final time = formatDate(dateTime, [HH, "\\h", nn]);

    return "$date $time";
  }

  static String toDate(DateTime dateTime, BuildContext context) {
    var locale = Localizations.maybeLocaleOf(context)?.toLanguageTag();
    final date = DateFormat.yMMMEd(locale).format(dateTime);

    return date;
  }

  static String toTime(DateTime dateTime) {
    String time = formatDate(dateTime, [HH, "\\h", nn]);

    return time;
  }

  static DateTime stringToDateTime(String stringDate) {
    return DateTime.parse(stringDate);
  }

  static String toDateTimeToStringFromFirestore(DateTime dateTime) {
    final date = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS").format(dateTime);

    return date;
  }
```

**EventViewModel**

```
class EventViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  DateTime get selectedDate => _selectedDate;

  void setDate(DateTime date) => _selectedDate = date;

  Future createInstructorEvent(Event event) async {
    final eventDocument = _db.collection("instructorsEvent")
        .doc();

    final json = event.toJson();

    await eventDocument.set(json);
  }

  Future editEvent(Event event) async {
    final fromString = Utils.toDateTimeToStringFromFirestore(event.from);
    final toString = Utils.toDateTimeToStringFromFirestore(event.to);

    _db.collection(instructorsEvent)
        .where("uid", isEqualTo: event.uid)
        .where("from", isEqualTo: fromString)
        .where("to", isEqualTo: toString)
        .get()
        .then((value) => {
          for(var element in value.docs) {
            _db.collection(instructorsEvent)
                .doc(element.id)
                .update({
                  "uid": event.uid,
                  "title": event.title,
                  "from": event.from,
                  "to": event.to,
                  "comment": event.comment,
                  "backgroundColor": event.backgroundColor,
                  "isAllDay": event.isAllDay,
                })
          }
    });
  }
}
```

**EventPlanningScreen**

```
class EventPlanningScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Event? event;

  const EventPlanningScreen({Key? key, this.event}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EventPlanningScreen> createState() => _EventPlanningScreenState();
}

class _EventPlanningScreenState extends State<EventPlanningScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final titleController = TextEditingController();
  final commentController = TextEditingController();
  late DateTime fromDate;
  late DateTime toDate;
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if(widget.event == null) {
      fromDate = DateTime.now();
      toDate = DateTime.now().add(
          const Duration(hours: 1),
      );
    }
    else {
      final event = widget.event!;
      titleController.text = event.title;
      commentController.text = event.comment!;
      fromDate = event.from;
      toDate = event.to;
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  //****************************************************************************
  // Free memory allocated to the existing variables
  //****************************************************************************

  @override
  void dispose() {
    titleController.dispose();
    commentController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: const CloseButton(
          color: white,
        ),
        actions: buildEditingActions(),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              buildTitle(),
              const SizedBox(height: 20,),
              buildDateTimePickers(),
              buildComment(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  //****************************************************************************
  // Editing actions
  //****************************************************************************

  List<Widget> buildEditingActions() => [
    ElevatedButton.icon(
        onPressed: saveForm,
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.done,
          color: white,
        ),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        label: const Text(
          validate,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16,
            color: white,
          ),
        ),
    ),
  ];

  //****************************************************************************
  // Title
  //****************************************************************************

  Widget buildTitle() => TextFormField(
    controller: titleController,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: addTitle,
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.5),
      ),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.orange),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.5),
      ),
      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.5),
      ),
      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.5),
      ),
    ),
    onFieldSubmitted: (_) => saveForm(),
    validator: (title) => title != null && title.isEmpty
        ? emptyTitleMessage
        : null,
  );

  //****************************************************************************
  // Date & time picker
  //****************************************************************************

  Widget buildDateTimePickers() => Column(
    children: [
      buildFrom(),
      const SizedBox(height: 20,),
      buildTo(),
    ],
  );

  //****************************************************************************
  // From
  //****************************************************************************

  Widget buildFrom() => buildHeader(
    header: from,
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: buildDropDownField(
              text: Utils.toDate(fromDate, context),
              onClicked: () => pickFromDateTime(pickDate: true),
            ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: buildDropDownField(
            text: Utils.toTime(fromDate),
            onClicked: () => pickFromDateTime(pickDate: false),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );

  //****************************************************************************
  // Drop down field
  //****************************************************************************

  Widget buildDropDownField({required String text, required VoidCallback onClicked}) =>
      ListTile(
        title: Text(text),
        trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
        onTap: onClicked,
  );

  //****************************************************************************
  // To
  //****************************************************************************

  Widget buildTo() => buildHeader(
    header: to,
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: buildDropDownField(
            text: Utils.toDate(toDate, context),
            onClicked: () => pickToDateTime(pickDate: true),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: buildDropDownField(
            text: Utils.toTime(toDate),
            onClicked: () => pickToDateTime(pickDate: false),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );

  //****************************************************************************
  // Header
  //****************************************************************************

  Widget buildHeader({required String header, required Widget child}) => Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text(
        header,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
      child
    ],
  );

  //****************************************************************************
  // Pick from date
  //****************************************************************************

  Future pickFromDateTime({required bool pickDate}) async {
    final date = await pickDateTime(fromDate, pickDate: pickDate);

    if(date == null) return;

    if(date.isAfter(toDate)) {
      toDate = DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day, toDate.hour, toDate.minute);
    }

    setState(() => fromDate = date);
  }

  Future<DateTime?> pickDateTime(DateTime initialDate, {required bool pickDate,
    DateTime? firstDate}) async {
    if(pickDate) {
      final date = await showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: initialDate,
          firstDate: firstDate ?? DateTime(2022, 4),
          lastDate: DateTime(2286),
      );

      if(date == null) return null;

      final time = Duration(hours: initialDate.hour, minutes: initialDate.minute);

      return date.add(time);
    }
    else {
      final timeOfDay = await showTimePicker(
        context: context,
        initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(initialDate),
      );

      if(timeOfDay == null) return null;

      final date = DateTime(initialDate.year, initialDate.month, initialDate.day);
      final time = Duration(hours: timeOfDay.hour, minutes: timeOfDay.minute);

      return date.add(time);
    }
  }

  //****************************************************************************
  // Pick to date
  //****************************************************************************

  Future pickToDateTime({required bool pickDate}) async {
    final date = await pickDateTime(
        toDate,
        pickDate: pickDate,
        firstDate: pickDate ? fromDate : null,
    );

    if(date == null) return;

    setState(() => toDate = date);
  }

  //****************************************************************************
  // Comment
  //****************************************************************************

  Widget buildComment() => TextFormField(
    controller: commentController,
    minLines: 1,
    maxLines: 5,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: addComment,
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.5),
      ),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.orange),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.5),
      ),
    ),
    onFieldSubmitted: (_) => saveForm(),
  );

  //****************************************************************************
  // Validate form
  //****************************************************************************

  Future saveForm() async {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();

    if(isValid) {
      final event = Event(
        uid: user!.uid,
        title: titleController.text.trim(),
        from: fromDate,
        to: toDate,
        backgroundColor: emailButtonColor.toString(),
        comment: commentController.text.trim(),
        isAllDay: false);

      final isEditing = widget.event != null;
      final eventViewModel = Provider.of<EventViewModel>(context, listen: false);

      if(isEditing) {
        print("Event to edit: \n"
            "uid: ${event.uid} \n"
            "title: ${event.title} \n"
            "from: ${event.from} \n"
            "to: ${event.to} \n"
            "comment: ${event.comment} \n"
            "backgroundColor: ${event.backgroundColor} \n"
            "isAllDay: ${event.isAllDay} \n");
        eventViewModel.editEvent(event);
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
      else {
        _addEvent(event);
      }

      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
  }

  _addEvent(Event event) {
    final eventViewModel = Provider.of<EventViewModel>(context, listen: false);
    eventViewModel.createInstructorEvent(event);
  }
}
```

What am I missing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Firestore only has a timestamp type.  There is no datetime type.  What you started with in "from" and "to" are string types to Firestore, not datetimes (you can tell because they are surrounded by quotes).

Comment: @Doug Stevenson
Thanks, yes that's true the DateTime is stored as a String. But if I don't update DateTime with DatePicker when I update data in Firestore. Why a String `"2022-08-28T15:00:00.000"` turn to a TimeStamp `28 août 2022 à 18:00:00 UTC+2` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think when you get the data you are formatting it and trying to push the formatted string to Firestone.. Try this instead

```dart
_db.collection(instructorsEvent)
        .where("uid", isEqualTo: event.uid)
        .where("from", isEqualTo: fromString)
        .where("to", isEqualTo: toString)
        .get()
        .then((value) => {
          for(var element in value.docs) {
            _db.collection(instructorsEvent)
                .doc(element.id)
                .update({
                  "uid": event.uid,
                  "title": event.title,
                  "from": fromString,
                  "to": toString,
                  "comment": event.comment,
                  "backgroundColor": event.backgroundColor,
                  "isAllDay": event.isAllDay,
                })
          }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've already try this before to post here and it doesn't work too. But even if nothing is upadted in Firestore when I change data in the app (title, from, to & comment)  the DateTime is still a String in Firestore with this so it's a good thing